# why ARM architecture necessarily dominates the IOT market?

Tags: arm, intel, arm7, x86, arm9

I would like to understand why do we use **ARM** for routers, cell phones, cameras, refrigerators, smart tv, and everything. instead of using any other architecture like x86.

**What are the advantages of using arm for these things?**

What would be the problems of simply using x86

Is It All About Cost, Size And Energy?

Comment: It's all about profit.

Comment: There is no problem using the x86,  there is both IOT product and toolchains for x86. Cost/performance/power are the driving factors for any product developer, and the low cost/power and reasonable performance of ARM generally wins out.

Comment: I don't know if you can buy x86 cores to put on your own product chip. I know you can't buy ARM processor, only their cores. Providing the IP is their business. So you can make the dedicated chip which you think fits just right in your market.

Comment: The cores are licensed to be built by anyone who pays an ARM and a leg

Comment: Just don't expect M$ to pay for this core to run on WIn10. and 75% of the British Arm Holdings company is owned by  a Japanese Bank.  Roots came from  Acorn RISC Machine. Can you say flops per microwatt per dollar?

Comment: Keil (De:USA) => ARM > IPO> < SoftBank Group 75%
Vision Fund 25%

Comment: There have been x86 phones, tablets, etc.  There are plenty of MIPs based IoT gadgets.  The question is all of too broad, too much seeking opinion, and too mistaken to have a definitive answer within the mission of this site.

Comment: x86 doesnt make cores.  intel makes chips and pushes the technology (among others).  Their flagship product is the x86 processor to ride on that tech if they could and did build others that could consume less power at the same performance but wont.  ARM makes ip not chips.  the question is not why does arm dominate but is why didnt mips dominate.  to some extent the quality, performance both power consumption and processing power

Comment: risc-v wont automatically take over as the cost to make even mcus is so expensive the cost is not in the ip you buy.  compared to the cost to develop or validate your own core, or buy a validated core from someone else, you are not yet better off than going with arm.  your up front cost is the same other than possibly schedule (years vs months), now it comes down to specs, power consumption, processing performance, size.  arm has ease of use features over risc-v.

Comment: there are choices from cadence and others, look at the esp8266. cant compete performance wise, but 8051s and z80s are still very alive and well.  there is likely one in the device you are using to read this, and countless numbers between that device and the servers and in the servers hosting these pages.  why?  license free and long time ago validated and small...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primary: Intel CPUs are faster in absolute sense (and maybe even faster per dollar), Cortexes are faster per amount of energy. Battery lifetime is a big issue for mobile use! Hence you see mostly Intel on mains-powered PCs, and Cortexes in battery powered appliances.

Secondary: Intel sells chips. You can buy any variation as long as Intel produces it. ARM/Cortex is an IP product: ARM licenses their CPU designs, so a manufacturer can add whatever he wants to the core and produce a chip to suit his needs.

Third: Intel used to be almost synonym with Windows, ARM used to be synonym with Linux. Windows is great for desktop use but not free, Linux is great for all kinds of servers, and it is free. Google choose Linux to base Android on.

Last: Cortex is not one CPU but a very diverse line of products, from very small ones (M series: cheap micro-controllers) to the big ones (A series: to run Linux). For the smaller ones Intel has little to offer in alternatives (8051? you must be kidding), and Cortex has pushed most of the non-Intel alternatives way back too. So in this field Cortex is realy dominant. (Also because in this field it makes even more sense to combine the CPU with manufacurer-specific peripherals on the same chip.)

Comment: "ARM used to be synonym with Linux." umm, Linux started it's life on Intel and is far better supported there than on anything else. ARM has been a common choice for mobile devices since long before they were mostly based on Linux kernels.

Comment: Quite subjective answer. If you didn't know the Linux story about supporting different ISA:s and SoCs, perhaps no need to push imagination as it is real. ARM badly supported by (upstream) Linux kernel even now, and at the same time there are zillions of products. A bit more correct to put *ARM is synonym to Android smartphones*.